# How can I access unknown typed object's property names

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I use a function which contains *object* type parameter. I want to get name of this unknown typed object's properties. How can I do this?

KR,

Dakmaz

Comment: See Reflection - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx)

```
var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a parameter of type object, use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) instead.

You can then [constrain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) this generic to implement an interface or inherit from a base class.

You will then be able to access the properties and functions defined in the constrained interface/base type. You can also define your own interface and constrain to it.

Example code:

```
public void MyFunc<T>(T myParam)
   where T : IEnumerable // or some other interface or base class.
{
   foreach (var child in myParam) // uses the interface IEnumerable that the generic was constrained to
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/

> I use a function which contains object

I smell bad code design.